# Database schema for food records

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am creating a calorie counting webpage. And I am not sure about MongoDB database schema for food records. It should work like this:

- day is separated into parts (breakfast, lunch, dinner)
- you can save a food record into one of those parts. e.g. Egg - 3x50 (grams) (3 eggs)
- there is a page for every day. Page is separated into day parts and recorded food is listed here. There is a food information - calorie count/proteins/... per food/day part/day

I have a food collection. 
example:

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectID("X"),
  name: "egg",
  calories: 140,
  protein: 12,
  ...
}
```

(calories and proteins per 100g)

Food records collection. example:

```
{
  food: ObjectID("X"),
  count: 3,
  weight: 50
}
```

And I am not sure where to save information about day parts / days. Should I save it in food record?

```
{
  food: ObjectID("X"),
  count: 3,
  weight: 50,
  day: "2015-11-05",
  part: "lunch"
}
```

Or should I create a separate collection for day parts?

What is the most effective way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MongoDB, your schema design depends largely on

a) The size of the collection (remember there is a 16MB collection cap)
b) How you are going to query the data

Since it looks like you want to see what you had for breakfast, lunch and dinner, you could probably use this schema:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId(....),
   "day": "2015-12-01"
   "part": "lunch",
   "foodEaten": [
   {
    "foodName": "eggs", 
    "serving": 2,
    "caloriesPerServe": 21,
    "proteinsPerServe": 34,
    ...
   }, 
   {
    "foodName": "pancakes", 
    "serving": 3,
    "caloriesPerServe": 367,
    "proteinsPerServe": 0.23,
    ...
   },
   ....
   ]
}
```

If you have users, you can link the user by adding a user key: value (user information would be in another collection). If you think that the collection will surpass the cap of 16MB, you can create a separate food collection and reference it in the foodEaten array. Since I don't know the scope of your project, I don't know if this will be the case, but I believe that this might be the best schema for your database.

You can check the MongoDB documentation for more information or [this video](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/schema-design-basics-1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one more question. Should I really embed all the food info in array? There could be a lot of nutrition values (protein, carb, fat, sodium, few types of vitamins and so on...). I guess it is still better to embed it than going throught each single food documents if I want to show all the values.
I also want to show sum for the day of all parts and its food and its nutrition values (sum of proteins, ...). Should I create another attributes in the schema you provided for sums?

Comment: If you think there is going to be a lot of information on that collection, you can reference it in the "foodEaten" array and just add the amount you ate (e.g { "foodEaten": [ {"food": ObjectId(...), "serving": 2}, ... ] }). Honestly, if you need to do calculations like the sums for the day, it is going to be more efficient  if you keep the document embedded. There might be a lot of repetition, but the queries will be faster. Finally, if you want to store the sums, you can add them to the document after the "foodEaten" array.

Comment: No problem! I hope that schema helps.